# What are these line and dot graphs called?

Tags: information-graphics, flat-design, minimalistic

I am looking for some kind of minimalistic network graphs but I can't find the right words to describe them.

A while ago, I discovered a webpage that has these kind of graphs but I no longer find it.

I have tried terms such as: "big data visualization", "network graphs", "design network graphs", "stock network graphs"...

An example of what I am looking for:

[image: Example 1]

Or the background logo used on this site itself:

[image]

I am just looking for a graph (minimalistic or flat design) with lines and nodes.

This is a similar website that I found:

http://personalbrandinstitute.com/

Comment: Your image is 2d, but the linked website background, has nothing to do with a graph, it's a **2d/3d mesh** instead.

Comment: Are you seeking to just gather images of this nature or to create them???

Comment: I suppose these could be called a lot of things as they are used for different things: constellations, star maps, node maps, etc etc. The real question is what you need them for? Are you seeking to replicate the style for something specific?

Comment: I am just seeking to gather images, not creating them. Just for graphic design purposes.

Answer (score 2):

These are just simply graphs. Altough in this case they are most likely formed by force direction so they could be called [force directed graphs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) because thats the layout. Not to be confused with directed vs nondirected graphs.

It is pretty easy for you to generate your own graphs in about 3 minutes with tools like:

- yEd
- [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/)
- Graphwiz

Comment: Thanks @joojaa - I am just looking for one image that is already designed. I will have a look at force directed graphs.

Comment: +1 @Alex they're also sometimes called "network graphs", "node diagrams" and "node-link diagrams". [**D3**](http://d3js.org/) has some great features for creating force-directed graphs, and is an open source library that a coder can use to create them. Example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly it but you could have a look at "concept map" or "mind map" or "network map". The difference between what you need and these 3 types of diagram is they often have a central point.

> Instead of using "graph" in your keywords, you could use the word
>   "map" and add "diagram"; you could get more results.

**Mind map diagram:**

[image: Mindmap example]

**Concept map diagram:**

[image: Concept map diagram]

**Network map diagram:**

[image: Network map]

---

If you only need the style of graph, maybe this will help finding more examples. If the data are "decorative" and the graph is for style only, maybe the easiest is to draw it yourself in Adobe Illustrator.

The keywords of the map's names above might help you find an online software to do them. In your sample it's only dots and lines though.

**Examples stock picture/footage using "network map" keywords:**

http://www.istockphoto.com/vector/abstract-technology-communication-illustration-45960120?st=b64993a

http://www.istockphoto.com/vector/connect-america-23751764?st=b64993a

http://www.istockphoto.com/vector/communication-technology-45549932?st=b64993a

http://www.istockphoto.com/vector/germany-network-map-37966800?st=b64993a

http://www.istockphoto.com/video/network-map-still-camera-16468015?st=b64993a

http://www.istockphoto.com/vector/global-networks-vector-illustration-for-your-business-45779688?st=b64993a

Etc.

---

<sup>Source: mindmap - ntpro.nl, Concept map - uofa.ualberta.ca, Network map - scientometrics.files.wordpress.com</sup>