# What this networking grid style effect called?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustrator-scripting

[image: Network stock image]

what is this effect called like dots connected to each other ?

I want to create this effect in Illustrator , is there is any script or plug-ins available in market to create this? , i tried " Distribute on path" script but i just could not create it. Client wants this design in the part of website so i needed to create it.

**Image is stock image , Image courtesy : [Shutterstock video](https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-7180375-stock-footage-digital-network-d-animation.html?src=rel/18651743:0/gg)**

This is from Graphic Design perspective

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are these line and dot graphs called?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55290/what-are-these-line-and-dot-graphs-called)

Comment: I needed for design purpose and that answer shows graph maker tools so in a way little different.

Comment: @DaveRajan most of those tools can export eps so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "networking grid" is an apt description.

I don't think you'd need a script to do this. It's fairly simple to create something like that manually, and by the time you find a script and mess around with it, you could have done it already.

In Illustrator create a dot symbol, and spray the symbol randomly with the Symbol Sprayer Tool. Then Expand the symbol set.  Then connect the dots with lines. Enable Smart Guides to make the job easier.  The example below took a few minutes.

[image: Example network grid]

Comment: I tried to do that but dots are getting selected together and i couldn't ungroup them : [link](https://imgur.com/a/cfFED)

Comment: Edit : Expand Helped me to Solve that Problem. still connect each dot with lines is pain. i am trying all points script but it is not applying to group and in ungrouped object , it just internally join points in each circle.

Comment: @DaveRajan Yes, expand. Sorry I forgot to add that part to my answer. I've edited it now to include that step. Joining the dots is easier with Smart Guides enabled.

Comment: +1 @Billy Kerr ,This will help for sure

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered that this effect is often referred to as 'Plexus'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another simple process: (no script involved). The idea is to turn all anchor points into circles. I use a scatter brush for better control.

1. Create a scatter brush form, based on a single circle.
2. Draw your "network" with pen tool.
3. Select and copy it.
4. Then go Select > Object > Direction Handles.
5. Hit delete key. You should be left with the anchors only.
6. Apply formerly created scatter brush to those anchors. They should
   turn into circles.
7. Paste in place the copied network.
8. If necessary, adjust circle size using Form panel

See example below:

[image: dots on anchors]

Comment: +1 @Vinny , is that dot's can further expand ?

Comment: @DaveRajan Not sure I understand your question. You can Expand them, yes! You can make them bigger too...

Comment: @BillyKerr : my Pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

More correctly, this is referred to as a Plexus network - and there's an After Effects plug-in Plexus 3 which will help do this readily.

Refer to this previous question & answer for further details in that context.

[What is this «minimalistic dots» video style called?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110858/what-is-this-minimalistic-dots-video-style-called/110880#110880)

There are a number of Illustrator plug-ins and scripts which can approach this, but I think I like @Vinny 's proposed answer - though I'd add that for me, I'd probably simplify this a whole lot - draw each line as an individual line, set the arrowheads at each end to the appropriately-sized dot, use Smart guides to snap.

Done.

[image]

Hope that helps.