# What is this «minimalistic dots» video style called?

Tags: style-identification, video, minimalistic

Found quite an interesting (in my opinion) video style with «minimalistic dots».

Direct link: https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/498479/Themes/Alt36/alt_new_logo.mp4

What is this «minimalistic dots» video style called? Is there any guides or flexible template to make such video?

Comment: Why would it be a template, rather than original work?

Comment: Yes, it is probably original work, but it does not mean there is no such templates

Comment: What makes you think it has a name?  Not everything has a name!  There are words you could use which would describe what it looks like.  To me, it these look like animations of molecules, especially the double hellix which looks like a DNA molecule.

Comment: There isn't a specific name, but you can name it what you'd like. "Dot-themed" seems like a good name to me :P

Comment: The following text my help you find some results: geometry particle dots.

Comment: The dots in the video tell a story, using many quite sophisticated ideas. If you know exactly which movement you want it might not be that hard to achieve. But the real problem is: Which story are you going to tell and which movements are you going to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What this networking grid style effect called?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/98949/what-this-networking-grid-style-effect-called)

Answer (score 3):

This sort of effect is referred to in the 3D motion graphics community as a ***Plexus network*** effect, ([Example 01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGpuQ0ioPrM), [Example 02](http://www.scriptspot.com/3ds-max/scripts/3d-plexus)) and this specific example you show seems to me to be a *vector 2D pseudo Plexus* - probably done in AfterEffects using techniques such as this [(tutorial video link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elHqinIm4RI) as I see clean vector edges throughout and no real atmospheric perspective, so probably the Plexus is not of actual 3D rendered origins, besides which, in this case the intersection and cross connection of the dots into the title motion graphics would make it really hard to have started in 3D.

As it happens [***Plexus 3***](https://www.toolfarm.com/buy/rowbyte_plexus_for_adobe_after_effects) by name is a mid price ($250) plugin for After Effects as well as a script used in 3DS, and so you CAN do full 3D plexus network effects in AE, as well as a host of other cool UI / UX type motion graphics; that said, I still think your example is pretty simple 2D work in After Effects.